# Excel VBA - Formula error in Calculating Neworking days

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement where in, I am trying to calculate the Days Passed / Remaining for the deadline.

This is the VBA Code,

```
DaysVal = NetworkDays.INTL(E2, Today(), 1, DateTable([Holiday]))
```

I got the value of the date that I am checking through Programatically like Colm & i

```
DaysVal = NetworkDays.INTL(Colm & i, Date, 1, DateTable([Holiday]))
```

DateTable[Holiday] is just a table full of dates which are holidays placed in a different sheet.I will be writing this DaysVal as a new column in the same sheet where I am taking the Colm[E2]

Please kindly correct me where I am going wrong with the Formula.

Share your thoughts.

Comment: `NetworkDays.INTL` is not a VBA function, unless you've written it as such elsewhere.  Perhaps you want to use the Excel worksheet function:  `DaysVal = WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays_Intl(...)`

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld Yes, I learned that with some research but even then I am not able to get a value through VBA. Do you have an working example sir?

Comment: Also, I read in a thread saying Networkdays won't work if I use the worksheet function command but rather just application.networkdays.....

Comment: Either works, but the error handling is different.  If you want an example, post an example of your data.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I got it to work almost. I have updated the answers. Kindly see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using the `Networkdays_Intl` function with a structured reference for the holidays range:

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
    Dim DaysVal As Long
    Dim StartDate As Date

StartDate = #1/1/2017#

DaysVal = WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays_Intl(StartDate, Date, 1, [DateTable[Holidays]])

End Sub
```

The holidays range could also be represented as:

```
Range("DateTable[Holidays]")
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks sir :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```
Function CalculateDaysDiff()

Dim A1DateValue As Date, DaysDiff As Integer
A1DateValue = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value

DaysDiff = Round(Now() - A1DateValue - 0.5)

CalculateDaysDiff = DaysDiff

End Function
```

I subtracted 0.5 because now() - someDate can return partial days (i.e. 1.8 days), and this rounded turns into 2, which probably is undesirable.

- If 'CalculateDaysDiff' returns a positive value, then you expired the deadline by 'DaysDiff' days.
- If 'CalculateDaysDiff' returns a negative value, then you have 'DaysDiff' days until the deadline.

Comment: Thanks. I got this to work through your method. I would still prefer the Excel Function though.But Thanks again. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the way to go, Still I am not able to get my company holidays as a holiday column, but got upto this.

```
StartDate = Range(Colm & i).Value
DaysVal = Application.NetworkDays_Intl(StartDate, Date, 1)
```

This works. Once, I get the holidays inside this. I will update my answer